# is quasicompact part of the definition of etale in EGA

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Is the projection map $\amalg_{i \in \mathbb{Z}} X \to X$ from an infinite disjoint union of copies of a scheme $X$ to $X$ an etale map, using the definition in EGA IV 17?
According to EGA, an etale map of schemes $f:X \to Y$ is locally of finite presentation and formally etale. Hence I don't think etale maps need to be quasicompact or quasifinite. However, wikipedia claims in property #5 under "Etale morphism" that etale maps are quasifinite, so either I'm missing something or wikipedia is using a different definition. I'm sorry to ask such a dumb question but this has come up repeatedly when I'm trying to read Champs Algebriques.

Comment: This error on Wikipedia has now been fixed.

Comment: A question which leads to an improvement of a wikipedia article, especially when it involves mathematics beyond the ken of most editors, is certainly a good and useful question.  No apologies necessary.  Bonne chance avec les champs. 

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, quasi-compact is not part of the definition of etale. Yes, your map from the infinite disjoint union to $X$ is etale.